# Day of the Week Selector with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

So I am trying to figure out the best way to validate if a single day is selected. As of now the validation works and when I submit it shows the error message. The issue I have is it's not scrolling to the day of the week selector. Now maybe I could write my model a little easier or the markup to build the day of week could use some love.

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { FormControl, FormHelperText, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

import { TClassSchedule, TScheduleBlock } from '../../types';
import { DayItem } from './DayItem';

export const DayOfWeek = ({ index, scheduleBlock }: TDayOfWeek): ReactElement => {
  // const theme = useTheme();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { control, formState, register, watch } = useFormContext<TClassSchedule>();
  const currentDay = dayjs();
  const sunday = dayjs().startOf('week');
  const monday = sunday.add(1, 'day');
  const tuesday = monday.add(1, 'day');
  const wednesday = tuesday.add(1, 'day');
  const thursday = wednesday.add(1, 'day');
  const friday = thursday.add(1, 'day');
  const saturday = friday.add(1, 'day');
  const occurrences = watch('occurrence');
  const { errors } = formState;

  const checkIfAnyDaySelected = (): boolean => {
    const { sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday } = scheduleBlock;

    return sunday || monday || tuesday || wednesday || thursday || friday || saturday;
  };

  const checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled = (day: dayjs.Dayjs): boolean => {
    if (occurrences === 'single') {
      return currentDay.format('dddd') !== day.format('dddd');
    }

    return false;
  };

  return (
    <Stack sx={{ marginBottom: '24px' }}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={`scheduleBlocks.${index}.id`}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <FormControl
              error={
                errors.scheduleBlocks &&
                errors.scheduleBlocks[index]?.id &&
                errors.scheduleBlocks[index]?.id !== undefined
              }
            >
              <Stack
                {...field}
                {...register(`scheduleBlocks.${index}.id`, {
                  validate: {
                    checkIfAnyDaySelected: () => {
                      const check = checkIfAnyDaySelected();

                      if (!check) {
                        return t('Please select at least one day');
                      }

                      return true;
                    },
                  },
                })}
                direction="row"
                spacing={2}
              >
                <DayItem
                  day={sunday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(sunday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.sunday}
                />
                <DayItem
                  day={monday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(monday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.monday}
                />
                <DayItem
                  day={tuesday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(tuesday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.tuesday}
                />
                <DayItem
                  day={wednesday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(wednesday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.wednesday}
                />
                <DayItem
                  day={thursday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(thursday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.thursday}
                />
                <DayItem
                  day={friday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(friday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.friday}
                />
                <DayItem
                  day={saturday}
                  dayId={scheduleBlock.id}
                  disabled={checkIfDayShouldBeDisabled(saturday)}
                  selected={scheduleBlock.saturday}
                />
              </Stack>
              <FormHelperText>
                {errors.scheduleBlocks &&
                  errors.scheduleBlocks[index]?.id &&
                  errors.scheduleBlocks[index]?.id?.message}
              </FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
          );
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};

export type TDayOfWeek = {
  index: number;
  scheduleBlock: TScheduleBlock;
};
```

And just in case here is day item component as well

```
import { ReactElement, useState } from 'react';
import { ButtonBase, SxProps, Theme, Tooltip, useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';

import { TClassSchedule, TScheduleBlock } from '../../types';

export const DayItem = ({ day, dayId, disabled = false, selected }: TDayItem): ReactElement => {
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(selected);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const dayDisplay = day.format('dd').slice(0, 1);
  const { setValue, watch } = useFormContext<TClassSchedule>();

  const baseStyles: SxProps<Theme> = {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: selectedDay ? theme.palette.primary.light : 'transparent',
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
    borderRadius: '50%',
    color: selectedDay ? theme.palette.primary.contrastText : theme.palette.primary.main,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    display: 'flex',
    fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamily,
    height: '33px',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    lineHeight: '17px',
    padding: '10px',
    userSelect: 'none',
    width: '33px',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: selectedDay ? theme.palette.primary.dark : theme.palette.primary.light,
      color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    },
    '&:focus': {
      backgroundColor: selectedDay ? theme.palette.primary.dark : theme.palette.primary.light,
      color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
      outlineColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
    '&:disabled': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[300],
      border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[300]}`,
      color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    },
  };

  const clickHandler = () => {
    const newSelectedState = !selectedDay;

    setSelectedDay(newSelectedState);

    const currentScheduleBlocks = watch('scheduleBlocks');
    const newScheduleBlocks = currentScheduleBlocks.map((block: TScheduleBlock) => {
      if (block.id === dayId) {
        return {
          ...block,
          [day.format('dddd').toLocaleLowerCase()]: !selectedDay,
        };
      }

      return block;
    });

    setValue('scheduleBlocks', newScheduleBlocks);
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip arrow title={day.format('dddd')}>
      <div>
        <ButtonBase disabled={disabled} sx={baseStyles} onClick={clickHandler}>
          {dayDisplay}
        </ButtonBase>
      </div>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export type TDayItem = {
  day: Dayjs;
  dayId: number;
  disabled?: boolean;
  selected: boolean;
};
```

Thanks and let me know if I am missing something